# Difference between "onMenuItemSelected" and "onOptionsItemSelected"

Tags: android

can someone explain me the difference between:

`onMenuItemSelected (int featureId, MenuItem item)`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onMenuItemSelected%28int,%20android.view.MenuItem%29

and

`onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29

in Android? I found a tutorial were someone overrides both methods.

```
// Reaction to the menu selection
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insert:
        createTodo();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.insert:
        createTodo();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Source: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Android knows about several types of menus (e.g. Options Menu and Context Menu). `onMenuItemSelected` is the generic callback. You don't need to use this usually. `onOptionsItemSelected` is the callback of the options menu and `onContextItemSelected` is the callback of the context menu. Use these two specific ones instead.

Comment: +1. Interesting issue, especially when using ActionBarSherlock, where you need compatibility with 2.3

Answer (score 10):

Using ADT 17 (version 4.2) the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback will allow the user to access menu options from any context including the Menu Button and the Action Bar.  As of Android version 3.0 the preferred method is the Action Bar which can be accessed from `onMenuItemSelected`.  If you are designing an app that supports versions 2.3 or earlier than `onOptionsItemSelected` is the way you want to go.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, onMenuItemSelected can be called by a Options Menu (Menu button) click or by Context Menu click.
Basically it just forwards the clicks to the other corresponding methods.

Look at the code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#2078